# Importing MapleTA Questions

Tags: maple

I have questions in a maple worksheet like this

```
q1 := Quiz("Find f'(x). f(x) = $P/x^2+ $T", 3, 
proc () local p, t, temp, tg, answer;
p := (rand(0 .. 100))(); 
temp := (rand(1 .. 2))(); 
tg := [sin(x), cos(x)]; 
t := tg[temp]; 
Quiz:-Set(`$P` = p); 
Quiz:-Set(`$T` = t); 
answer := diff(p/x^2, x)+diff(t, x); 
[diff(nextprime(p)/x^2, x)+t, diff(p/x, x), answer] 
end proc, 
style = multiplechoice, output = mapleta)
```

To export them, I use the following code

```
with(MapleTA);
currentdir("/path");
MapleTA:-Export([q1], "ques.zip");
```

When I try to import them on the mapleTA site, I get the following error, 
`Errors loading the question bank, ques.zip : Reason: Error at line 1. Line ended while reading variable name (missing "=" at end of name?)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That exported zip file from Maple is a Course Module in Maple T.A.

The error you report usually occurs when you try importing a Course Module as a Question Bank in Maple T.A.

To fix this, go to the Question Repository in Maple T.A. and click on Course Modules > Import. Then choose the zip file you got from Maple.